# Accessing download location and download event in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon

I am new to firefox addon development.

I am trying to access browsers download location set by user and the event that fires before download starts.

I checked references here but couldn't find anything relevant for my requirement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials

Is there any way to find that?

Answer (score 0):

To catch the even you can do so like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#Observing_downloads

The event holds information on where the user is downloading it to.